# How to store 10bit data into 8bit array with c?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have some data like this:
 
0 represent data
 
x represent empty
 
0000000000xxxxxx
 
10bit............6bit wasted

I want to compact it with the next data to save space.

I use bit shifting to do this.

|    8Bit    | 2Bit   6Bit | 4Bit  4Bit | 6Bit   2Bit |    8Bit    |

so far I have:

```
#define mask1   (char)((Data & 0xFF00) >> 8);  //apply mask
#define mask2   (char)((Data & 0x00C0) >> 6);
#define mask3   (char)((Data & 0xFC00) >> 10); 
#define mask4   (char)((Data & 0x03C0) >> 6);
#define mask5   (char)((Data & 0xF000) >> 12); 
#define mask6   (char)((Data & 0x0FC0) >> 6);
#define mask7   (char)((Data & 0xC000) >> 14); 
#define mask8   (char)((Data & 0x3FC0) >> 6);

switch (counter) {     //repeat after 4 times
    case 0:
         array[i++] = mask1;
         array[i]   = mask2;
         counter++;
         break; 

    case 1:
         array[i++]| = (mask3);
         array[i]    = (mask4);
         counter++;
         break;

    case 2:
         array[i++]| = mask5;
         array[i]    = mask6;
         counter++;
         break; 

    case 3:
         array[i++]| = mask7;
         array[i++]  = mask8;
         counter=0;
         break;
}
```

Comment: Hint: do it 5 bytes (4 x 10 bit values) at a time.

Comment: @Paul R -good suggestion I will try to do it that way

Comment: Do you really **need** to save that space? This will probably complicate matters more than it's worth.

Comment: @Len I need performance, the code will run in microcontroller and the data will save in a flash. I'm trying to save more space, maybe some memory access time.

Comment: @pstan: fair, but I'd be benchmarking first to see where you really will gain the most.

Comment: Warning to prospective respondents: This question is 6+ years old as of this writing.

Comment: Why not a struct with bit fields, rather than manually writing all this bit-shifting?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - ?? Good catch, but what's this doing on the top questions list then?

Comment: It was edited by one Mike a short while ago.

Answer (score 2):

A hack that should work is to cast the array, and move the array pointer.
It's better explained if I diagram this:

```
oooooooooo_____
        __oooooooooo____
                ____oooooooooo__
                        ______oooooooooo
                             >>>|<<<
                                        oooooooooo______
```

So if we were to implement the above idea, we'd get code that looks something like the below:

```
void convert(char* array, int arraySz, tenbitData* Data, int dataSz)
{
    char* arrPtr = array;
    int dataIdx = 0;
    int rollCnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataSz; i++)
    {
        ushort dat = dataSz[i] << 6 - ((i % 4) * 2);
        ushort* ariPtr = (ushort*) arrPtr;
        ariPtr[0] |= dat;
        arrPtr += ((i % 4) == 3 ? 2 : 1;
    }
}
```